# Connect SMB endpoint with Camel v3 and the camel-jcifs from camel-extra

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, smb, cifs

I have the following maven versions in my pom.xml (among others):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jcifs</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Camel spring-boot version = 3.7.0 and I want to connect to a SMB endpoint like this:

```
smb://sharedriveuser@server-instance.sub.domain.net/folder?initialDelay=0&delay=9000&autoCreate=false&noop=true&idempotent=true&password=ThePassWorD&filter=#csvFileFilter
```

I read the [Camel 3 Migration Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html) and found nothing regarding this camel-extras.

When trying to connect, I get an error like the password option is not supported anymore:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: smb://sharedriveuser@server-instance.sub.domain.net/folder?initialDelay=0&delay=9000&autoCreate=false&noop=true&idempotent=true&password=xxxxxx&filter=#csvFileFilter due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{password=ThePassWorD}]
```

The [actual documentation link](https://camel.apache.org/jcifs.html)  google found many times, seems dead.

From Maven central, there is no version 3.x of the lib `camel-jcifs` and I am wondering if the lib is still compatible with Camel 3.x.x, otherwise is there another alternative with Camel 3?

I also tried to downgrade the `camel-jcifs` to 2.24.3 with the same error.

Comment: there are too many changes from 2.x to 3.x => a 2.x lib will not work in camel 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a pull request to add camel-jcifs to the 3.x version:

https://github.com/camel-extra/camel-extra/pull/39

*You might also get my fork and build it yourself:*

- https://github.com/bebbo/camel-extra *

It got merged and is in the official repository:

https://github.com/camel-extra/camel-extra

To use it with quarkus, you have to convert some `List` types to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Camel-extras is a separated project from the Apache Camel. There is some work in place in the camel-extra repository to support camel 3[1], but it is still to be completed and there is no release in sight.

[1] https://github.com/camel-extra/camel-extra/commit/f028dfdfaa467958c58abea0d604f8fe2f17be04

Comment: Thx for your answer, hence the solution would be to keep the Camel 2.x until the port has been done? This is what I finally did and seems working better anyway.

Comment: For the moment yes.